# Sum value of all rows of a column with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this to get a total count

```
$exe = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(field_3) FROM t_a');
$res = mysql_fetch_row($exe);
echo 'Total Count: ' .$res[0] . ' / XX';
```

But I need it from multiple tables with the same structure, named t_a, t_b, all the way to t_z

Comment: You could use `(SELECT SUM(field_e) FROM t_a) + (SELECT SUM(field_e) FROM t_b) + ...`

Comment: you can select from multiple tables just put comma

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Union All](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) in my sql

```
select sum(field_3) total
from
(
    select field_3
    from t_a
    union all
    select field_3
    from t_b
) t
group by field_3
```

Comment: why `group by` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze It's because union will discard duplicate row.